# Wrap each item in horizontal list using CSS

Tags: html, css, listitem, horizontallist

I've got a horizontal list with long items that I want to wrap. The list wraps fine if one list item is really long or if all the list items are really short.

However, if two list items are both long, they will not split across the available space. This image shows the problem:

[image]

Here's the markup I'm using:

```
<html>
<style>
    ul {text-align:left; width:400px}
    li {float:left; padding-left:20px; list-style-type:none; display:inline; white-space:normal;}
    li a {display:inline; white-space:normal;}
</style>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">>alf; fa sadlf;</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="#">>a sdf; fa sd; asd;lfgj </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">>a sdfasdgsadlf; asd;lfgj asdgsadlf sd; asd;lfgj</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">>a sdg gj asdgsadlf; afg adfg asd;lkfalfgj</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really understand. Where are the items supposed to wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting rid of some of your code. If I understand correctly, all you'll need is the following:

```
 ul { width:400px; }
 li {
    list-style-type:none; 
    display:inline;
    padding-left:20px
 }
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/M9zqE/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to both of you! I wasn't thinking about the fact that the float was causing the inline not to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed by not floating items (thus not removing them from the flow)

See http://jsfiddle.net/pRCFR/